# Elastic load balancer - EC2s InService, but can't connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Just getting an Elastic Load Balancer up for my application servers, and I'm having trouble connecting.

I placed 2 EC2 instances behind the load balancer, and both of them are successfully connected and InService, but putting the URL of the load balancer into Chrome never receives a response - it just hangs forever.

The ELB is placed under the security group where all incoming/outgoing is allowed.

Amazon's documentation assumes that something is wrong with your application servers, but they both work great, and the health checks are passing.

Help?

**EDIT:** Not using CNAME, guys. This is for a backend service, so I'm using the bare public DNS provided by AWS automatically. It's like:
http://api-load-balancer-XXXXXXXXX.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/

And no, EC2 instances are also available to the internet gateway with a public url - One of these instances is currently being used for serving the application publicly, and it's working just fine for that. Just want some redundancy in case of failure, so I spun up another one.

Listeners is configured to only HTTP (port 80 on ELB, port 80 on instances).

Comment: silly question: did you add the cname of the LB to the dns?

Comment: Failing that silly question, another: Are your listeners configured correctly?

Comment: it is not the DNS, he is using the CNAME directly. But I bet your 2 EC2 instances are private ones, without any public IP. And when you created the ELB you used at least 2 private subnets from different availability zones, and those zones didn't have any public subnets?

Comment: Edit above answers these questions.

Comment: So, you're saying that you can access the EC2 servers directly and they work OK, the ELB has the same security group as the EC2 servers, the Health Check is working OK but you can't access the ELB via its DNS Name, eh? Only other thought is that your ELB is not in a public subnet. Otherwise, it seems like you've got everything working OK. You might want to fire up a test instance+ELB to make sure things work as normal, then figure out the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you just have to wait for 15-30 minutes before you will finally be able to resolve load balancer's IP address by DNS name. It happened to me when I was doing AWS tutorials.